# Can I develop my pipeline without checking in the yaml to master?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm new to the yaml build config game and as such I do a lot of trial and error. So I want to be able to test run my pipeline and see if it is working as I intended. But I don't want to have to check in the yaml file into my master branch for every incremental change to be able to test run it.

Is it possible to run a pipeline from a separate branch or without checking in code all together?

Thanks!

Comment: You can create another branch with the yaml and run the pipeline fro this branch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with Shayki, you can create a test branch based on the master branch. Then create a new pipeline.  Switch to the test branch in yaml.

[image]

The changes in this yaml will be committed to the test branch.

[image]

Comment: Ah! I didn't see that there. Thanks!